# List item align not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a ul with some li and I want the result to be like this:

```
  I. List element 1
 II. List element 2
III. List element 3
 IV. List element 4
  V. List element 5
```

but I get this result:

```
I. List element 1
II. List element 2
III. List element 3
IV. List element 4
V. List element 5
```

here is my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gbo969z1/)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an `<ol>` with `list-style-type: upper-roman;` ?  

(I posted this comment earlier, but with an error, corrected by another.  In order not to lead someone astray later, I've deleted the original and re-posted corrected code.)

Comment: @BobBrown i removed the comment, you can remove me from comments...:)

Comment: OK... I've done that, but I really believe in credit where credit is due, especially when I make an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
span{
   display:inline-block;
   width:30px;
   text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, one more question: how can I make the bullets dissapear?

Comment: See my comment to your question, about using `ol`.

Comment: You can use: ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

Comment: @Flopet17 It should be `ul li {list-style: none;}` for best practice.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1

Change the `<ul>...</ul>` to `<ol type="I">...</ol>` – `ol` is an ordered list, [`I` means uppercase roman numerals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol), already formatted exactly how you need them.

#### Method 2

Change the `<ul>...</ul>` to `<ol>...</ol>`, but specify the uppercase roman numerals in CSS instead of HTML:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

#### Method 3

Methods 1 and 2 are best – as you can see they save a lot of messing around with custom `span`s, and `<ul>` is supposed to only be used for lists where the order is irrelevant. If you really need to use `<ul>` like in your question, then add `display: inline-block;` to your `span`s (you can't give them a width otherwise), and add `list-style-type: none` to the `ul` and `li`s, to hide the bullet points (you might want to remove the `li` left margins too).

---

All 3 methods can be seen working [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbo969z1/2/).

Answer (score 2):

No need for the span tags. You can do this..

```
<ol type="I">
   <li>Item desc</li>
   <li>Item desc</li>
   <li>Item desc</li>
   <li>Item desc</li>
   <li>Item desc</li>
</ol>
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/1L0wdggL/1/

## -or

```
 <ol>
    <li> Item desc</li>
    <li> Item desc</li>
    <li> Item desc</li>
    <li>Item desc</li>
    <li> Item desc</li>
</ol>

li {
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/1L0wdggL/2/

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS

```
li {
display:flex;
}
```

Comment: This is not supported by IE9 and earlier just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Just change all `ul` tags to `ol` and remove  tags.

You need to add type with ol like that:

```
<ol Type="I">
```

There are following types you can use with  ordered list:

```
Type="i"
Type="a"
Type="A"
```